# Objectify 4 Filter not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm trying to do a simple JUnit test to do a query like this:

```
Resource result = ofy().load().type(Resource.class).filter("raw =", 
    "/Bob/-/userId/-/").first().get(); 
if (result != null){
    System.out.println("Resulting Resource raw =" + result.getRaw());
}
```

The query above results to `null`, however when I do a query using id (which is a Long type) I get the result. When I persisted the entity I'm trying to 
query I logged the `@Id` and the value is `1`, so I did a query using `id` to check:

```
Resource result = 
    ofy().load().type(Resource.class).filter("id =", 1).first().get(); 
if (result != null){
    System.out.println("Resulting Resource raw =" + result.getRaw());
}
```

The resulting `result.getRaw()` is `/Bob/-/userId/-/` which is really weird, from my first query the result should have not been `null`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if you Have an @Index on that field, If you try to select by field that doesn't have an index you'll get null even that it is there.
On several fields you'll need index on all of them of course.

*Index of more than one field will be placed in the datastore-indexes.xml https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Comment: Do you know if it's supposed to work in development ? Addin `@Index` doesn't help me :(

Comment: Dont forget that you can have several index in the "datastore-indexes.xml" file depending the data you are quering (it works the same for most of nosql db)!