# GAE Objectfy - Why should I add @Index on Field to use that in filter condition

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am completely to new to `Objectify`. I am using `Objectify` for GAE application , I have one interesting question in `Objectify` `filter` condition

I am to executing a `load` method to do some filter like

```
objectify.load().type(User.class).filter("email", userEmail).first().now();
```

My Question is, above  statement doesn't work until I mark `email` field in **User** Entity class as `@Index` ? Why is this required ? . If we don't put @Index on field, we get `null` result.

Could some one clarify my doubt, I am little concern about marking my fields as @Index as it might **cost** **space** and it(@Index) is one of the candidate to grow data in GAE Datastore.

Thanks to SO post [Objectify 4 Filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871579/objectify-4-filter-not-working) . It helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered above, your issue isn't actually with Objectify, but rather how the datastore works. You will find it very difficult to work effectively using objectify without understanding the basics of the datastore. You can read the general docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) and specifically about querying [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Queries_and_indexes).

The short answer is, that the datastore is only able to match entities to queries if the fields you are querying on are indexed for that entity. Objectify gives you an annotation to achieve this with, consistently across all entities of a given kind.

The reason you must specify each field to index is that indexes have a cost associated with them when you write entities, so having fine grained control is important.

Answer (score 2):

GAE queries only follow indexes. If you don't index a field, it won't show up in a query result set. This is the nature of GAE.

Comment: But my question is WHY ? could you elaborate more on this. Why it has that nature, what could be the reason.

Comment: [AppEngine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes) say, "App Engine predefines a simple index on each property of an entity". Does Objectify 'unindex' so that only annotated fields are indexed?

Comment: @Ashish Yes, App Engine predefines an index for each property of an entity, but it doesn't populate the index with values for an entity unless that property is indexed for that entity.  For example, you could have two Objectify-annotated classes for the same kind, one of which indexes property "foo" and one which does not.

Comment: "predefines a simple index" is a confusing statement and shouldn't be present in the GAE docs; that's probably worth filing a bug against in the GAE issue tracker. In the low-level api there are two methods on Entity: setProperty() and setUnindexedProperty(). You call one or the other.